# Facebook Comments Plugin not visible on local server

Tags: facebook, localhost, facebook-social-plugins

I tried to set facebook Social-comments plugin for my website running on local server, but the comment section is not getting visible for my Web url for Localhost

## Working for Main Url

[image: Works]

## Does'nt work for subpage url

[image: Doesnt work]

**Anyone knowing Solution please give answer**

Comment: Facebook tries to scrape the given URL, so I don't think localhost URLs will work. You will likely need to use a publicly available URL.

Comment: @CBroe but how it Still works for localhost:5500

Comment: Sorry, couldn't tell you. But you should be able to use almost any sort of public URL for testing.